# Submitting an app only for iPhone 5/5s/5c

Tags: iphone, app-store

I've worked on my application for a couple of months, I hired a designer to do the UI and every screen in the app is based on 3 main elements - top bar, bottom bar and content.
I tried to use auto-layout and setting the top and the bottom bar was a piece of cake, but the image I use for a background in the content view shouldn't be resized (it's based on circles and they turn into ellipses). 
Is there a way for me to submit the app only for the iPhone 5/5s/5c?

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify device types within the iPhone category.  Your best bet is either to design a layout that can work for both screen sizes, re-design the layout so it automatically displays a "4S version" and a "5 version" depending on the user's device, set it to a ScrollView so the user just scrolls up and down to see the full page, or design it so the individual elements can be cropped (or squeezed together) on the smaller screen without actually resizing the individual pieces.

Comment: Alexander is correct. The App Store determines device requirements based on a minimum required iOS version, not a particular hardware iteration. Don't forget about the newer iPod touches with a 4" screen. There are specific APIs to determine whether a device has the required hardware (such as GPS, camera, etc). But requiring a 4" screen only because you don't have a background image for a 3.5" screen is likely to cause approval problems when you submit the app to Apple for review.